# cbind, grep and quotation marks in R

Tags: r, regex, cbind

Consider a minimum working example (for, e.g. a binomial model):

```
test.a.tset <- rnorm(10)
test.b.tset <- rnorm(10)
c <- runif(10)
c[c < 0.5] <- 0
c[c >= 0.5] <- 1
df <- data.frame(test.a.tset,test.b.tset,c)
```

Using a regex, I want to regress `c` on all variables with the structure `test."anything".tset`:

```
summary(glm(paste("c ~ ",paste(colnames((df[, grep("test\\.\\w+\\.tset", colnames(df))])),
        collapse = "+"), sep = ""), data = df, family=binomial))
```

So far, no problems. Now we get to the part where `cbind` comes into play. Suppose I want to use a different statistical model (e.g. `rbprobitGibbs` from the `bayesm` package), which requires a design matrix as input.
Thus, I need to transform the data frame into the appropriate format.

```
X <- cbind(df$test.a.tset,df$test.b.tset)
```

Or, alternatively, if I want to use regex again (where I even add a second `grep` to ensure that only the part inside the quotation marks is selected):

```
X2 <- cbind(grep("[^\"]+",paste(paste("df$", colnames((df[, grep("test\\.\\w+\\.tset", colnames(df))])), 
            sep = ""), collapse = ","), value = TRUE))
```

But there is a difference:

```
> X
            [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] -0.4525601 -1.240484170
 [2,]  0.3135625  1.240519383
 [3,] -0.2883953 -0.554670224
 [4,] -1.3696994 -1.373690426
 [5,]  0.8514529 -0.063945537
 [6,] -1.1804205 -0.314132743
 [7,] -1.0161170 -0.001605679
 [8,]  1.0072168  0.938921869
 [9,] -0.8797069 -1.158626865
[10,] -0.9113297  1.641201924
> X2
     [,1]                        
[1,] "df$test.a.tset,df$test.b.tset"
```

From my point of view the problem seems to be that `grep` returns the selected value as a string inside quotation marks and that, while `glm` sort of ignores the quotation marks in `"df$test.a.tset,test.b.tset"`, `cbind` does not.
I.e. the call for X2 after the paste is actually read as:

```
X2 <- cbind("df$test.a.tset,df$test.b.tset")
```

Question: Is there a way to get the same result for `X2` as for `X` using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `grep("test\\.\\w+\\.tset", colnames(df))` will return the indexes of columns that match your pattern. If you wanted to build a matrix using just those columns, you could just use:

```
X3 <- as.matrix(df[,grep("test\\.\\w+\\.tset", colnames(df))])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. 
For better understanding two more questions: First, why then does it work for `glm`? I suppose it is because `glm` can also take column indexes instead of names as an argument. 
Second, if I modify `grep("test\\.\\w+\\.tset", colnames(df), value = TRUE)` and incorporate it into the example, it still yields the same result. Why? `value = TRUE` does not seem to have any affect at all in this context. If it did, the initial result should read `"df$1,df$2"` in my understanding?

Comment: You can index a data frame by column number or name. If you have data frame `df` with columns a, b, and c, then `df[,c(2, 3)]` and `df[,c("b", "c")]` are the same. For `glm`, you are passing a string which is being converted to a formula via the `as.formula` function; you're not trying to run a command. If you want to run the command stored in a text string, use `eval` and `parse` (something like `eval(parse(text="2+2"))`). However, this is generally bad coding practice.